# PyQGIS: how to get a list of all textlabels in my Layout

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3, layouts

I have a print layout with a bunch of items, two text labels among them. For the pluging I'm wrting right now I need a list with the two text labels. My initial idea was 
`labels = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layouts().QgsLayoutItemLabel().currentText()`

However when I try to execute my plugin I get the following python error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'QgsLayoutItemLabel'

Any ideas how to get a list with the text labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have only one print layout active, you could use the following to get all labels and the text they contain:

```
labels = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layouts()[0].items()
for x in labels:
    if isinstance(x, QgsLayoutItemLabel):
        print(x)
        #To print the text inside the labels
        print(x.text())
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the `items()` return the objects from the layout but some of them return as QT objects that are not manipulable with *PyQGIS*, so it is not possible to modify and access the properties of all the items in the layout.

To obtain all the objects and access to the properties is required the following process:

```
layout = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layouts()[0]

qitems = layout.items()

for qitem in qitems:
    qitem.setSelected(True)

layout_items = layout.selectedLayoutItems()

for item in layout_items:
    if isinstance(item, QgsLayoutItemLabel):
        print(item.currentText())
        print(item.text())

layout.deselectAll()
```

- The `currentText` returns the text as it appears on the label (with evaluated expressions and other dynamic content).
- The `text` returns the label’s preset text.